# How to custom format number

Tags: javascript

i was looking many format number using javascript but still cannot find exactly what i need.

format numbers i looking for:

```
5000000000000000000000000 => 5.00
50000000000000000000000000 => 50.00
500000000000000000000000000 => 500.00
5000000000000000000000000000 => 5,000.00
50000000000000000000000000000 => 50,000.00
500000000000000000000000000000 => 500,000.00
```

i was tried something like this:

```
var set2 = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
}).format(data);
var VOLFixed = parseFloat(set2).toFixed(2);
```

and etc

Comment: `5.000.00` - I don't think this format exists anywhere. If you want it German, it should be `5.000,00`, and if you want it English, it should be `5,000.00`, but with `5.000.00` it's very confusing!

Comment: im sorry, its my fault, i already edit my question. @CherryDT

Comment: This `50,00` and `500,00` are from what country?

Comment: Still confusing, now you have it mixed - in your example you now have German format in 50 and 500 but English format everywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide your number by 10<sup>24</sup>, which seems to be the scaling factor you have, and then format:

```js
function format (data) {
  return Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  }).format(data / 1e24)
}

console.log(format(5000000000000000000000000))
console.log(format(50000000000000000000000000))
console.log(format(500000000000000000000000000))
console.log(format(5000000000000000000000000000))
console.log(format(50000000000000000000000000000))
console.log(format(500000000000000000000000000000))
console.log(format(5000000000000000000000000000000))
```

This is assuming that you want a comma as thousands separator and a dot as decimal separator - your question is currently a bit confusing in that regard.

Comment: thats all, tysm!